# Advice on books?

Tags: discussion

I have 1 hour of travel by train now from home to work and I really would like to start reading a bit, mostly about networking and security but also about programming.

I've been collecting some list of books so far but I would like to ask the community if they are appropiate for my knwoledge or not, if they would suggest any more, etc.

Basically, the question is: is it possible to post something like that here? Not only books related, but any other kind of resource.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's a close reason on almost all SE sites for this sort of question, which is generically called a "shopping question:"

> Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Comment: Alright, I see.. and understand that. It's a pitty tho, some expert advice would be great here :)

Comment: @Alex Once upon a time, we did do shopping questions.  Feel free to search them out if you want to find practical examples of why this kind of question doesn't hold up well to the test of time.

Comment: I'll do, I may find an answer to my questions and yeah.. I can already see the huge amount of spam Ward was talking about..

Comment: @Alex go to reddit for open-ended questions